# Can you use function notations for relations as well?

Tags: functions, relations

This question might have the obvious answer: no. But, for the purpose of giving a relation a name and specifying the input variables... is it wrong to use function notation for a relation?

For example, is it correct to design a question that begins with... consider the relation r(x) = ...?

I would love to know your thoughts. Thanks!

*Update: I was asked to provide some additional context for this question. I'm a teacher teaching a course in Advanced Functions course in high school and trying to fix some content about inverses of functions. And since there is already one answer here, I'll add that our relations will be defined by some sort of equation, so it looks like it will be ok to use.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's a good idea, big-O notation does use function notation for a relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of notations that work for functions work with relations too. For example, the composition of two functions $f$ and $g$ defined by:
$$
(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))
$$
is a special of the composition of two relations defined by:

$$
x (R \circ S) z \Leftrightarrow \exists y(xRy \land ySz)
$$

However, functional application notation: $f(x)$ does not work for arbitrary relations. E.g., if $<$ is the ordering relation on the integers, what does $(<)(0)$ mean? The closest you can get to it is the (functional or relational) image operation: if $A$ is a subset of the domain of $f$ (or $R$), the image $f[A]$ (or $R[A]$) means $\{f(x) \mid x \in A\}$ (or $\{ y \mid \exists x \in A\cdot xRy\}$). (Many authors write $f(A)$ rather than $f[A]$, but I think the square brackets make a useful distinction.)

Comment: Thank you. In our context, we're mostly distinguishing between relations and functions that can be described with equations. For example, if I want to discuss a function, but only as its relation, I wanted to make sure that it's still ok to use the notation.

Or, if there was a question that started with, "consider f(x) = ..." and ask them the talk about it's inverse, if it exists. Does the inverse exist for f(x) as a function (or does it exist only as a relation)?

It seems like we'll be ok to do this though. Thanks again!